# Apps distributed internally via enterprise account. Profile supposed to be expired, but still working

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I have apps distributed internally via enterprise account.

Previously, when a profile are expiring, user got a message "profile will expire in ...".

Now, I have a strange situation.  I have an app with a profile who was supposed to be expired since one month. ... and the app still working\installing without any warning\problem. (the ipa was generated more than one year ago, so I can be more sure that profile was expired.)

Are apple removed the 1 year max expiration for the profile?  Or does Apple have change the way it was manage(validated only when the developer compile ipa) ??

Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device will use a newer profile if one is available on the device.  If you have installed other apps on those devices which have a newer enterprise profile that has a wildcard app id, it may be that you've inadvertently updated the provisioning profile on the devices without re-installing the original app.

We had this happen with one of our apps where only certain users were complaining that they couldn't run an older app.  It turned out that the users who only had installed the older app had the expired profile, but users who had installed a second app (which had the newer provisioning profile / certificate) were able to run the app fine.

If the certificate / profile is truly expired, you've stumbled upon something else, but I suspect if you were to inspect the profiles on the devices, you would find a newer profile on the device (either through MDM, or through installing another app like in our case).  Here's more information from another answer I posted: [Enterprise Deployment certificat and profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098337/enterprise-deployment-certificat-and-profiles/29121777#29121777)