# How to manage Enterprise Distribution Provisional profile expiration?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, enterprise

Currently, I'm Working on enterprise application which are installed on several devices, And now situation is provisional profile gonna be expire soon, But application certificate doesn't expire for another couple of years.

So, we want to make smooth process for application provisional profile renew.

Already refer:

- [Renew-ios-provisioning-profile-on-in-house-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038586/renew-ios-provisioning-profile-on-in-house-app)
- [Enterprise Distribution Provisioning Profile Expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594876/enterprise-distribution-provisioning-profile-expiration)

So, now question is if i'm creating new provisional profile and make build again and after application updated by user. It ask for **permission for verify application** in device settings?

Any help much appreciated..

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the user has already trusted your organisation's enterprise developer membership then they will not be prompted again.  Best practice is to use an MDM to distribute enterprise apps.  That way you can just publish a new provisioning profile without needing to install a new app version

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11...  And which is best option for provisional profile creation. Edit existing one or create new one ?. And if i'm going to edit existing then is their any problem with existing installed app.?

Comment: Watch this - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/705/

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you.. :)