# what happens if apple certificate of type "Mac development" expires?

Tags: ios, macos, certificate

In April, a certificate from an private site delivered app I'm maintaining will expire. This certificate is of type "Mac development". I do not grasp many of apple certificate's nuances.

I am linked in a "enterprise" account, my app is delivered via private site

From what I understand reading here on stack and the apple docs, it is a certificate that is required both while I'm developing/working on the app, or when I'm distributing the app.

My doubts are:

1. what else is needed for?
2. what happens to delivered apps if the certificate expires?
3. is this the "development" certificate or is something different?
4. is something required on the Mac I'm using or by the app itself?
5. does the user need to download again my app if I update the certificate?

UPDATE - added screenshots

the certificate that is about to expire

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Development` certificates are used for development and testing only, you can't distribute Apps with this certificate. You may want an `In-House / Ad Hoc` or `Distribution` certificate.

1. I don't really get it. Need for what? Generally, `Development` certificate for development & testing. `Distribution` for Mac App Store.
2. Like I said above, you can't, at least on your Mac. However, there are distribution certificates in one developer account. Maybe others can deliver the App. Or tell them to export that certificate for you.
3. This `Development` certificate allows you or team members to run App, enable services during development and testing.
4. Open KeyChain -> Login -> My Certificates, you will see it here.
5. No, users don't need to, just developers.

Comment: ok thank you, I red around that some functionalities (not clear which) could not work well on delivered apps with expired cert. Also, this app is delivered  via company site, not app store. I'm now on certificates management, but totally new about them. On apple profile page there are multiple certificates regarding this app,I see all of them not only on keychain, so do not know wich mac uses it since I must update other people about incoming expiring certificates I also need to understand then explain their usage and requirements such will the delivery apps keep up working?

Comment: These certificates will do nothing with your app if it is delivered.

Comment: could you take a look to this? the original question - answer it is a bit confusing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787835/expiring-mac-development-certificate-will-shut-down-my-delivered-app-distributed

Comment: Yeah but your certificate is `Development` right? In-house distribution is for Enterprise account.

Comment: I am linked to enterprise account, I will update both questions with this info. does it change everything?

Comment: I am still quite sure it does not affect any deployed apps on current devices. It may stop the App with bundleID matched with this provisioning which is signed with the development certificate, but only on debug mode. I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594876/enterprise-distribution-provisioning-profile-expiration), take a look. In short, it may impact the bundleID, that is signed to the certificate. And in-house IPA can't install manually device by device by debug mode (dev cer), you should have a link for installation somewhere (distribution cer).